# string to JsonObject in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, json

What is the best way to convert a (properly Json-formatted) `String` object into a `System.Json.JsonObject`?  Right now I create a `StringReader` and use `System.Json.JsonObject.Load`.

(This is really kind of academic, since I think I'll always be dealing with the raw Json in `System.IO.Stream` form.)

Comment: Why would you deal with the Json raw?

Comment: What I meant was, I'll never have the Json in String format, it will always come from the web service in a Stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the `System.Json.JsonValue.Parse` static method to parse a string directly rather than use a `StringReader`.

Comment: Whoa, how did I miss that one.  Thanks.